# C++ logger for Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows, logging

I have written a simple logger in C++ on Windows that I want to use to log info and errors from multiple threads to DbgView:

```
// dbg.h
inline void dbg_info(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "INFO:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << s << std::endl;
    OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
}

inline void dbg_err(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "ERROR:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << s << std::endl;
    OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
}

struct dbg {
    class out : public std::stringstream {};
    class err : public std::stringstream {};
    struct Flush {};
    static Flush flush;
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const dbg::Flush& a);

// dbg.cpp:
#include "dbg.h"

dbg::Flush dbg::flush;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const dbg::Flush& a) {
    std::ostream* pos = &os;
    dbg::out* out = dynamic_cast<dbg::out*>(&os);
    if (out) {
        dbg_info(out->str());
    }
    dbg::err* err = dynamic_cast<dbg::err*>(&os);
    if (err) {
        dbg_err(err->str());
    }
    return os;
}
```

Usage:

```
 dbg::out() << "value = " << value << dbg::flush;
```

or

```
 dbg::err() << "error = " << error << dbg::flush;
```

Is my code safe in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: As far I can see no. You need to make functions which should be thredsafe atomic, by using mutex or any similar concept.

Comment: @convert:I think that each thread works on its local data (which is thread safe): 2xstd::stringstreams + 1 std:string.
Multiple threads also work on dbg::flush at the same time, but that is a static variable so it should be thread safe?
See Meyer's singleton.

Comment: And what that OutputDebugStringA do? Why static variable should be threadsafe?

Comment: @convert:Not sure if static variables are always thread safe.
But in this case the static variable is just being read from different threads.
I think that should be safe. Many threads can read the same variable at the same time.
That does not change the variable so there is no way the variable can become corrupt.
Data corruption occurs when multiple threads write to the same variable:
thread 1: counter = counter + 1; thread 2: counter = counter + 1;
If unlucky the counter has now only been incremented once.

Comment: Yes as long you only read that variable, no meter if static or not, it´s threadsafe.  But that OutputDebugStringA could be problematic, not understanding what it does.